# C macro for OS X version (Lion or not) detection?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Is there a predefined C macro for detecting the version of OS X? I know `__APPLE__` and `__MACH__` exist, but those are binary. Is there a specific value for `__APPLE_CC__` that indicates Lion?

In particular, Lion added a definition of `getline()` to `<stdio.h>` in Lion and it would be nice to be able to detect whether or not code was compiling on Lion or not to work around compilation errors.

Specifically, I'm referring to building Unix C code in Bash (outside of XCode).

Comment: *Compiling* on or *running* on Lion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Availability.h` macros allow you to check for compile- and run-time version dependencies.  See the discussion [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

Answer (score 4):

Check in `/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h` - it contains macros such as:

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7
    #define DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER    DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE
#else
    #define DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER
#endif
```

I came across this stuff because 'openssl/sha1.h' has been slathered with 'deprecated' attributes for Lion, so compiling `git` gets warnings galore.