# Cabal "os" flag with operating system version

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'd like a flag that is conditioned on the version of the OS, and not just the OS:

```
if os(darwin) && os-version() >= 10.7
```

or

```
if os-version(>=10.7)
```

or something with that behavior.

I could do it with `make` and `sw_vers -productVersion`, but I want to keep the Cabal file with `build-type: Simple` (I mean it even has a `frameworks` field).

Context: I have some bindings to some Cocoa functions that were introduced in OSX 10.7 or so. I'd like Cabal to not try to build on older Macs, rather than spamming the person installing the package with unhelpful "symbol not found" errors or whatnot.

https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations (Under "conditions") seems to say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. Cabal does not offer this feature. Here's the [relevant ticket](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2517). However, for OS X you don't need to necessarily move from `build-type: Simple`. Rather you can use `CPP` and the macros provided by apple, as discussed at [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024961/c-macro-for-os-x-version-lion-or-not-detection).