# How to detect Mac OS X version using C preprocessor?

Tags: c, macos, c-preprocessor, os-detection

I want my C code to be compiled successfully on different versions of Mac OS X. One problem I have is before OS X Yosemite I need to `#include <vecLib/clapack.h>` to make lapack work. However, vecLib can't be founded on later versions.

How can I detect the version of Mac OS X and then include the header I have depending on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include <Availability.h>

#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 101000
    #include <vecLib/clapack.h>
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some explanation — the coding of Yosemite (10.10) and the origin of the name and any pointers to documentation that explains it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024961/c-macro-for-os-x-version-lion-or-not-detection) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025023/499581) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025021/499581) might already cover it.